# How to make cleveref and nameref work with documentclass wlscirep and \section*?

Tags: sectioning, cleveref, subsection, nameref, wlscirep

**QUESTION: How to make `cleveref` and `nameref` work with `\documentclass{wlscirep}` and `\section*`?**

Note that `\documentclass{wlscirep}` comes from "[Template for submissions to Scientific Reports](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns)". Here following I show the cases I tested with `cleveref` and `nameref`:

**(1) `cleveref` works with `\documentclass{article}` and `\section`**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section{Methods}\label{test}
We see in \cref{test} that ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

**(2) `cleveref` does not work with `\documentclass{article}` and `\section*`**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Methods}\label{test}
We see in \cref{test} that ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

**(3) `cleveref` works with `\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}` and `\section`**

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section{Methods}\label{test}
We see in \cref{test} that ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

**(4) `cleveref` does not work with `\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}` and `\section*`**

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Methods}\label{test}
We see in \cref{test} that ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

**(5) `nameref` works with `\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}` and `\section`**

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\section{Methods}\label{test}
We see in \nameref{test} that ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

**(6) `nameref` does not work with `\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}` and `\section*`**

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Methods}\label{test}
We see in \nameref{test} that ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is clever ref suppose to return here? Perhaps yuo should explain what your end goal is instead. Then there might be better ways

Comment: Since the section doesn't have a number, what do you expect \cleverref to do?

Comment: You are both right... I edited my question.. :-)

Comment: You want package `nameref` and command `\nameref` instead of `cleveref` and `\cref`.

Comment: I agree with cabohah it is `nameref` you need, as far as I know cleverref does not collect the title of a sectional command.

Comment: ```nameref``` works for ```\documentclass{article}```, but it does not work with my ```\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}```. Should I modify the current question or open a new one?? In addition, even though it worked, it would not have the link to bring you to the corresponding section of the document - Instead, with ```\cref```, by clicking on the name (in the PDF), it would bring you to the corresponding section of the document...

Comment: You should specify where that class comes from as it is not on CTAN

Comment: Yes, sorry, ```\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}```
comes from "Template for submissions to Scientific Reports", 
(https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns)

Comment: The class is terribly written, and loads `hyperref` before loading `titlesec` to modify sections. Just a guess, but that's not a good combination and is a possible source of the problem. If I were you I would not use this class at all.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment @AlanMunn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class uses titlesec and titlesec doesn't properly support hyperref and nameref. You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}

% loaded by the class
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% new code
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\leavevmode\MakeLinkTarget[section]{}\ignorespaces#1}
  []  

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\def\ttl@straight@i#1[#2]#3{%
  \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2}
   {\NR@gettitle{#3}}
   {\NR@gettitle{#2}}
  \gdef\ttl@savemark{\csname#1mark\endcsname{#3}}%
  \let\ttl@savewrite\@empty
  \def\ttl@savetitle{#3}%
  \gdef\thetitle{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \ttl@labelling{#1}{#2}%
  \ttl@startargs\ttl@straight@ii{#1}{#3}}

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section*{Methods}\label{test}
We see in \nameref{test} that ...

\section{Normal}\label{test2}

\nameref{test2}

\section[short]{Long}\label{test3}

\nameref{test3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Manyyyy thanks @Ulrike Fischer! Very nice :-) It works also by using ```\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}```  (instead of ```\documentclass{article}```) :-)